# Unanswered closed as duplicate questions in the Related sidebar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

While looking at the "Related" sidebar section for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051646/laravel-request-file-change) for which I posted an answer, I saw another unanswered question with which I could help out ([What is difference between Input::all() and request()->all() in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888828/what-is-difference-between-inputall-and-request-all-in-laravel-5)). However, when I went to this question, it had already been closed as a duplicate.

Is it useful to have unanswered closed questions show up in the Related section? It seems that if the question is unanswered and closed, it is not likely to contain any useful information, and could be replaced by another related question which may help.

Furthermore, for questions that have been closed as duplicates, would it make more sense to show the linked "original" question instead of the closed duplicate?

And finally, if nothing else, would it make sense to show the status ([closed], [duplicate], etc) in the title, like you see in the question list, or even in the "Similar Questions" sidebar I can see while writing this question right now?

Answer (score 2):

I was just composing something along these exact lines, but then your post showed up in the sidebar. So, I'm dumping my original thoughts into an answer.

---

When I'm looking at, and possibly answering, a question, I look at the "Related" sidebar to see if anyone else has an unanswered question. Quite frequently, the Related includes questions that are considered unanswerable.

[image: Related Sidebar Box]

It seems to me that it's pointless to include these if they aren't supposed to be answered. If the decision is made to keep them in that box for some unknown reason, it would be nice to be able to just filter them out ourselves since it's unhelpful to trawl through them.

I think the style of such topics could be changed. This can be something like a little icon (lock, etc) beside the link, change the color of the vote box (like green meaning accepted answer), and/or add some other indicator beside the link like the [closed], etc, text mentioned above.

Somewhat related, but only vaguely, is the issue of ancient issues having 20+ answers, but none of them will ever be accepted because the OP moved on. It would be nice if someone could flag an answer as accepted (similar to Microsoft forums and the like), close it as abandoned, or something. It's not helpful to contribute to a multi-answer question from 4 years ago that has a good solution in at least one of the answers.