# What does a duplicate of an unanswered question do to the tag statistics?

Tags: support, tags, statistics

How does [this kind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319525/5994041) of question count in [unanswered statistics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/topusers) under the tag? If I understood it right, question with non-accepted answer without any upvotes is treated like an unanswered one, so...

What happens when another question is marked as a duplicate of an unanswered question? Is it treated as an answered one, because the answer is in the original question even if original is unanswered, or do you get your count of unanswered questions under the tag incremented, because... reasons? Does original remain unanswered, or will it be changed to "answered" after a new question is marked as a duplicate of the original?

Comment: A question can only be marked as a duplicate of an unanswered question if both questions were asked by the same person.

Comment: @RobertLongson and what happens to the statistics? Will there be now two unanswered questions or will there be one answered(the duplicate) and one unanswered(original post), or how does it work? I'm just curious, because this kind of behavior may cripple a whole tag's (unanswered)statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed questions are ignored by the unanswered statistic.